how do I get rid of one keyboard layout?
I don't know how it happened, but I have three keyboard layouts instead of just two and I don't see it anywhere in any settings, just in the keyboard switcher and it is really annoying as I don't want that Czech QWERTY. I want only Czech and English (United States)


the first language pack has only one keyboard layout Czech QWERTZ and that's what I want

the second one has also just one, so where the heck is this Czech QWERTY and how do I remove it?


You use this and adjust it for the keyboard layout you want to remove
